# How do I build an executable for an application written in Swift from the terminal?

Tags: macos, swift, terminal

I'm asking how to do this outside of Xcode.

A Swift script written in a text editor can be executed with `xcrun swift hello_world.swift` or `swift hello_world.swift`. They can also be set to executable and run with a shebang. This is parallel to a scripting language like Python.

But since Swift is a compiled language, I'm sure there has to be some way of building a Swift executable through the Terminal using `swift`, `clang`, etc. Has anyone found anything regarding this? I've surprisingly found nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `swiftc`:

```
% cat > hello.swift << EOF
heredoc> println("Hello, world!")
heredoc> EOF
% swiftc hello.swift 
% ./hello 
Hello, world!
%
```

If you want to compile multiple files, the one you want to actually run on launch needs to be called `main.swift` (in which case you probably also want to use `-o executablename`).

Various options available via `swiftc --help`.  The most likely one you want to use is `-O` to turn on the optimizer.

Also, depending on your environment settings, you may need to use `xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc`, if you are using `Foundation` or other SDKs.

Comment: Works for general cases, but fails when adding lines like `import Foundation`, where I receive the output:

`<unknown>:0: error: cannot load underlying module for 'CoreGraphics'
<unknown>:0: note: did you forget to set an SDK using -sdk or SDKROOT?
<unknown>:0: note: use "xcrun -sdk macosx swift" to select the default OS X SDK installed with Xcode`

Following the general advice given does not work. Any additional insight?

Comment: ’twas the edit I was working on when you posted this :)

Comment: How I create functions and call her?

Comment: How to use Podfile?