# How to create binary / script files for terminal

Tags: swift, xcode, terminal, executable, binaryfiles

I created a small program:

```js
struct Person{
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    func sayHello() {
        print("Part 1")
        print(firstName)
        print(lastName)
        print()
        
        print("Part 2")
        print(firstName, lastName, separator:"\n")
        print()
        
        print("Part 3")
        print(firstName, lastName)
        print()
        
        print("Part 
        print(firstName, terminator:" ")
        print(lastName)
        print()
    }
}

let aPerson = Person(firstName: "x", lastName: "z")
aPerson.sayHello()
```

Though, I'm having trouble converting this code onto terminal..

Within the terminal I wanted to recreate this program..

1. As a compiled executable binary that can be executed from the Terminal.
2. As a script file that can be executed from the Terminal.

I found this post:
[How do I build an executable for an application written in Swift from the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045495/how-do-i-build-an-executable-for-an-application-written-in-swift-from-the-termin)

Though, I'm not sure how to interpret that well

Comment: Are you asking how to compile a swift file into an executable that can be ran in Terminal?

Comment: I think that's what is meant by binary, and I also want to do it as a script file 
@Miket25

Comment: The link you gave provides a working answer. Besides the syntax error in your code, when fixed and compiled through Terminal and ran, it works fine. I don't quite see the issue?